# Nuxt getting query parameter

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to get the q parameter from

```
http://localhost:3000/search?q=myterms
```

however, i can't seem to figure out why it gives me an error

> Cannot read property 'q' of undefined

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  Query: {{ query }}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    watchQuery: ['q'],
    name: 'Search',
    computed: {
      query() {
        return this.$route.params.query.q
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style></style>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$route.params is for route params `url/<param>` and $route.query for query string params `url?q=<value>`

```js
computed: {
    query() {
      return this.$route.query.q
    }
  }
```